# Expresso-store - order email notification custom email address

Tags: expresso-store, notification

**3) Purchase notifications**

Each ‘product’ will have an ‘owner’, this will either be the author of the entry or a custom filed with an associated emails address.

**Question 3:** Can we vary the order notification ‘to’ email address based on this custom fields or the entries Authors email address? For example, if I was the owner example@example.com and someone ‘purchases’ shop item I am the owner of, I would get the the email notification.

Answer (score 2):

Nope - the email you set in the email notification setting for each email is fixed.